# Flutter: RadioListTile color is not changing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-design, listtile

I have a `RadioListTile` in my widget tree which has the property `tileColor`, whenever I change its value it doesn't actually change.

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for this problem is to just wrap the `RadioListTile` with a `Material` widget and you will find that the problem is gone.

Example:

```
Material(
   child: RadioListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.red,
   ),
)
```